Route does not match required types of NextJS route, authOptions | NextJS Route Type Error
I'm encountering an issue with NextJS routes while working on an project (ecommerce), and I could use some guidance in resolving it. To be more specific, it's got to do something with my route.ts file which also works with NextAuth (because of providers like Google). In development everything is working fine, though when I try to build the project, I get errors. Btw, I'm using NextJS 14 and I'm following a YouTube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaiijESQH5o&list=PL3bsHl112k-ZZyeH3gZgDwqJYvDu6rgY3&index=1), the problem happened at around 5:00:00 when building the project... I also tested it by copying source code (without luck).
Now like I said, in dev mode everything is working fine and good. However, when I try to build the project, using npm run build, I get this error:
Type error: Route "src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts" does not match the required types of a Next.js Route.
  "authOptions" is not a valid Route export field.

Here are the probably relevant files:
app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts
import { mergeAnonymousCartIntoUserCart } from "@/lib/db/cart";
import { prisma } from "@/lib/db/prisma";
import { env } from "@/lib/env";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter";
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import { Adapter } from "next-auth/adapters";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma) as Adapter,
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    session({ session, user }) {
      session.user.id = user.id;
      return session;
    },
  },
  events: {
    async signIn({ user }) {
      await mergeAnonymousCartIntoUserCart(user.id);
    },
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

My authOptions are being imported and used in other files, though I don't think it's necessary to provide that code. I am still open to try out and and give other information on my codebase.
Here's minimal reproduction code for those who want to reproduce the issue, don't forget to install next-auth. (src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts):
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [],
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };



Can you provide a minimal reproduction?

@ZihanHu just create a new NextJS project (npx create-next-app@latest) with all defaults. Then navigate to your project and run npm install next-auth in Terminal to get the required next-auth dependency. In your project structure, create a new folder inside src/app called api, containing a folder auth, containing a folder [...nextauth] with a route.ts file. There you can paste in the code from my minimal reproduction code (see post) and at last run in Terminal npm run build where the error is supposed to occur

Removing the export from the line export const authOptions will work.
For some reason, it does not like to have two exports in the route file.

All Route Handlers need to have one of the following names:

GET
POST
PUT
PATCH
DELETE

In your case, you can't export the same function as GET and as POST.

My issue was a little more simple. Instead of this:
export async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch('https://data.mongodb-api.com/...', {
    next: { revalidate: 60 }, // Revalidate every 60 seconds
  })
  const data = await res.json()
 
  return Response.json(data)
}

I needed the route handler to use the GET name:
export async function GET() {
  const res = await fetch('https://data.mongodb-api.com/...', {
    next: { revalidate: 60 }, // Revalidate every 60 seconds
  })
  const data = await res.json()
 
  return Response.json(data)
}


So what are you trying to mean with that in my context? Is there a particular file you are talking about because I don't seem to have (any problems with) a file with a getData function...

Btw, I got around this by just downgrading my next-auth version. It may be just temporary but anyways the tutorial is a bit older...

Consider providing more details on which version you downgraded to and why it resolved the issue. This will help others facing the same problem.

@IlyaKhrustalev, for me it was enough to use next-auth 4.22.1 along with next 13.4.7 and typescript 5.1.3
