NextJs Error "post" is not a valid Route export field
I trying to build this route.ts in NextJs13+ whith typescript:
export default function post() {...}, but when run npm run build I got the error: does not match the required types of a Next.js Route.   "POST" is not a valid Route export field.
Another observations is that I've lint rules to make export default if only one export is needed, in my case is just POST method.
I trying change to uppercase, arrow function, but nothing works well.
One solution is to create async function handler() {...} and at the end of file route.ts put export {handler as POST, handler as GET}, but this don't make sense for me at all.
I'm using next 14.2.12.

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78407624/route-does-not-match-required-types-of-nextjs-route-authoptions-nextjs-route

No, my code export only one HTTP export default asyn function POST() {...}. The case that you send me is considering that route.ts is exporting not valid objects for this feature in NextJS, the export const authOptions..., size authOptions is no HTTP method at all.
